# Breaking up a large SQL file into many files executed from the main file in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, module

I want to break a large SQL file (many queries and temporary tables) into: a main SQL file and a list of other SQL files, which would then be executed from within the main SQL file.

For instance, the main SQL file would look as follows:

```
EXECUTE file1

EXECUTE file2

EXECUTE file3

..do something..

EXECUTE file 4

..do something..
```

Comment: Such a requirement would be specific to your client.  If you're using the mysql command-line tool, you can use the `source` command: see [Executing SQL Statements from a Text File](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-batch-commands.html).

Comment: Make each query a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work - SQL is executed on server, not on your local machine, so no EXECUTE file is available.

What can you do is to wrap all SQL chunks into corresponding procedures, create procedures in your database and then execute them in order.